# How to enable assertions when running code(tests) with maven?

Tags: java, maven-2, assert

I wish to run my projects tests using maven with the assertion facility enabled (assert).
Normally I would set an argument when launching the JVM, How Can I do such a thing with Maven?

Comment: Can you show your pom file? And why you think the assertions are not activated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the defaults of the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) cause it has already activated the [assertions](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#enableAssertions)